# R: Add new column based on condition with multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I have made a dataframe which has a column with dates and 3 columns with numeric values, either 1 or 0:

```
Date      Test1  Test2  Test3
18-3-2016   1      0      0
18-3-2016   0      0      1
19-4-2016   1      0      0
12-2-2017   0      0      0
15-2-2017   0      0      0
```

I want to add a new column which places either 1 or 0 based on which values are in the 3 test columns. Only if **all** test columns have the value 0, then I want the new column to have the value 1. If **any** test column has value 1, then it should return value 0 in the new column. The new desired dataframe will look like this:

```
Date      Test1  Test2  Test3  New
18-3-2016   1      0      0     0
18-3-2016   0      0      1     0
19-4-2016   1      0      0     0
12-2-2017   0      0      0     1
15-2-2017   0      0      0     1
```

So I want the new column to only return value 1 if **all** the other columns are equal to 0, otherwise it should place the value 0.

I already tried some code but it seperated all the columns and gave an undesired output:

```
df$New <- ifelse(df[2:4] >0, 1, 0)

Date      Test1  Test2  Test3  New.Test1  New.Test2  New.Test3       
18-3-2016   1      0       0      0            1         1
18-3-2016   0      0       1      1            1         0
19-4-2016   1      0       0      0            1         1
12-2-2017   0      0       0      1            1         1
15-2-2017   0      0       0      1            1         1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ifelse()` idea was a good approach, with the difference beeing in the condition:

```
df$New <- ifelse(df$Test1 == 0 & df$Test2 == 0 & df$Test3 == 0,
                  1,
                  0)
```

`&` specifies that all the requirements have to be fulfilled simultaneously, meaning that each Test value has to be 0 to assign 1 to the new column.

Answer (score 4):

You could try a conditional based on their sum? So like if all 3 added together is 0, make the new column 1. Like so:

`df$New <- ifelse(df$Test1 + df$Test2 + df$Test3 == 0, 1, 0)`

Comment: Thank you for the great solution!